# How to have the 'string line' in the same scope as the 'getline(in,line)' in a 'while(getline(...))' loop?

Tags: c++, scope, while-loop, getline

Example:

```
std::ifstream in("some_file.txt");
std::string line; // must be outside ?
while(getline(in,line)){
  // how to make 'line' only available inside of 'while' ?
}
```

Do-while loops won't work for the first iteration:

```
std::ifstream in("some_fule.txt");

do{
  std::string line;
  // line will be empty on first iteration
}while(getline(in,line));
```

Of course one can always have a `if(line.empty()) getline(...)` but that doesn't really feel right.
I also thought of abusing the comma operator:

```
while(string line, getline(in,line)){
}
```

but that won't work, and MSVC tells me that's because `line` isn't convertible to bool. Normally, the following sequence

```
statement-1, statement-2, statement-3
```

should be of type `type-of statement-3` (not taking overloaded `operator,` into account). I don't understand why that one doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of how either version of `getline()` works. I would suggest looking at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/ - it doesn't return a boolean.

Comment: @Brian: It seems you have the misunderstanding. :) `getline` returns the passed-in stream object, which is implicitly convertible to `void*` which is implicitly convertible to `bool`. Or in C++0x, the stream objects will be implicitly convertible directly to bool in boolean contexts such as `if`, `while` etc.

Comment: I don't understand.  Why won't the for loop version work?  `line` will not be empty on the first iteration.  The condition statement is executed before the loop is entered.

Comment: @Benjamin: ARGH! That's the result of listening to people without testing myself. :< That's embarassing... Maybe kindly change that comment into an answer, I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A for loop will work, I do this all the time:

```
for (std::string line;
     getline(in,line); )
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reminding me not to trust other people unless you tested it yourself... :)

Answer (score 6):

You could cheat a little bit and just make a superfluous block:

```
{
    std::string line;
    while (getline(in, line)) {
    }
}
```

This isn't technically "the same scope", but as long as there's nothing else in the outer block, it's equivalent.

Comment: Yeah, that would kinda be the last resort. :P

Comment: This solution isn't too bad. This block of code should probably be moved to a separate function (callled *ProcessLines* or something). Modularity is win!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `for` loop:

```
for(std::string line; getline(in, line);) {

}
```

I don't think this is very good style, though.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that style. But I prefer the while loop (but that's just a taste thing).